# Draw table in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I’d like to display a table of values and be able to select cells.

How would I do this in Pharo Smalltalk? I’ve heard talk of Morphic widgets able to do this, but I’m still really new to Smalltalk.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at Spec. But I have no idea if there is any support for that

Comment: Glamour can probably do that too (http://www.moosetechnology.org/tools/glamour)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674116/are-there-any-open-source-spreadsheet-implementations-in-smalltalk-which-are-use

Answer (score 2):

I would look into TreeModel class side examples.

I used to do that:

```
tree := TreeModel new.
tree openWithSpec.

tree columns: (Array 
    with: (TreeColumnModel new displayBlock: [:node | node content first asString ]; headerLabel: 'Name'; yourself)
    with: (TreeColumnModel new displayBlock: [:node | node content second asString ]; headerLabel: 'Last Name'; yourself)
    with: (TreeColumnModel new displayBlock: [:node | node content third asString ]; headerLabel: 'Age'; yourself)
    with: (TreeColumnModel new displayBlock: [:node | node content fourth asString ]; headerLabel: 'Gender'; yourself)).
```

then set the tree roots.

Are you in Pharo 3 or Pharo 2 ? This works in Pharo 3.

Comment: That's really cool! But it's more of a fancy list than a grid. I.e. you can select rows but not cells...