# How to draw a Table with cells in pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

i'm new to smalltalk and i come with a problem. 
i'm trying to draw a table where the attributes of the variables shown. 
i found this answer to a similar question that i'm doing here: [Draw table in Pharo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304099/draw-table-in-pharo) , but in there it's not clear how to create or fill the cells.

I would appreciate any help.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To receive help you should try something first. Then show us your code (or a part of it) and ask a concrete question about it.

Answer (score 1):

On the class side of `FTExample` there are some examples you can run of different kinds of lists and tables.